# Escalera vertical en juego 2D

Tags: script, unity, game, 2d

A ver estoy diseñando un juego en 2D con unity, pero estoy buscando solucion para hacer un metodo en el script de mi personaje principal donde al entrar a un collider2D(con un Trigger2D)colocado en su sprite de escalera vertical, este pueda activar su animacion de climb y pueda moverse hacia arriba,anulando la gravedad y al salir del collider poder activarla de nuevo

Comment: y por qué no progrmas exactamente lo que dijiste, anular la gravedad lo haces modificando la masa a 0 del personaje, anulando la gravedad del personaje con gravity = 0 etc...

Answer (score 0):

Despues de investigar y con ayuda de un profesor logramos que el personaje subiera las escaleras y se desplazará en ella:

Al entrar y salir de la escalera:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider2D)
{
    if (collider2D.tag == "Player")
    {
        collider2D.GetComponent<PlayerController>().MoveStair();
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collider2D)
{
    if (collider2D.tag == "Player")
    {
        collider2D.GetComponent<PlayerController>().ExitStair();
    }
}
```

En el controlador del personaje:

```
[SerializeField]
private bool _isClimbing = false;

public void MoveStair()
{
    _isClimbing = true;
    _rigidBody2D.gravityScale = 0f;
    _animator.SetTrigger("Climb");
    Debug.Log("Entro en una escalera");
}

public void ExitStair()
{
    _isClimbing = false;
    _rigidBody2D.gravityScale = 1f;
    _animator.SetTrigger("ExitClimb");
    Debug.Log("Salio de una escalera");
}
```

Nota: al terminar de subir de la escalera el personaje no logramos que bajara, por un tema de boxcollider(usando platform effector 2D).